# Avoiding data cleanup for "undefined" or "wrongly defined" categories in database?

Tags: database, validation, database-design

I am trying to create a library management system, and have books and their genre stored. The admin can add new books to the system and select its genre from the predefined list, but if the book fits in none of those genre, he can choose "Other" option and type his own new genre. How can I make sure the admin is not entering any invalid data such as "asdf" or "xyz"? This is necessary as I will be using column genre to recommend related books on the customer side.

Comment: Unless you add relevant code, tables definition and the database engine you are using, this is just too broad.

Comment: You either have to trust the admin to enter something that makes sense OR you have to make him/her choose from a predefined list of all possible valid choices - in which case there probably won't be an "Other" option.

Comment: Assuming it is a cloud based application. Can we a regular data cleanup of data generated and make sure the data remains valid after every cron-job? And if so what are the techniques that will help in achieving this ?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's cloud-based or toaster-based, if you only want to allow the admin to enter "valid data" you're going to have to define that somewhere - probably in another table.